# How do the current Illuminati, Age of Ultron, and Avengers story lines connect?

Tags: marvel, avengers, fantastic-four

I can never keep up with the different story lines. Its all a doozy.

> - So the Illuminati with their gems are fighting some kind of alternate reality earth.
> - Age of Ultron has the world in ruins and most supers dead, and Nick Fury and friends are traveling time to try and fix it
> - Avengers is fighting Ex Nihilo on Mars
> - Fantastic Four apparently left Earth and present time to find a cure for Reed, yet they are in all story lines?

All of these stores are published in different titles which are published at the same time. So it seems to me that Iron Man is fighting alternate Earth, Ultron, and Ex Nihilo all at the same time at different places. Are they happening in different points of time? Or are they happening on different parallel Earths?

So confused. Please help set this straight. Thank you

Comment: Unclear exactly what your asking.  Would be helpful if you can articulate a specific question.  BTW - any particular reason for the spoiler tag ?

Comment: Spoiler because people may not have read the comics? What I'm asking is how do they relate to each other? How are the events happening chronologically? If I follow the publication, then Captain America and Iron Man are fighting Ex Nihilo (Avengers), Ultron (Age of Ultron), and alternate earth (forgot what the title is) all at the same time. Is one supposedly happening in the past and another in the future? Or are they all happening on different parallel Earths? This happens to me in comics all the time. Multiple X-Mens, multiple Avengers, multiple Iron Mans, etc @_@

Comment: Also, the FF left Earth and current time to find a cure for Reed, yet somehow there is a tie-in into Age of Ultron where Reed and Susan came back to Earth, leaving Franklin and Valeria in outer space, and Reed was killed by Ultron... except in the latest Fantastic Four he's still in outer space and the FF just battled a villain from the negative zone. Wait what? @_@

Answer (score 1):

As I'm currently reading through the Avengers books from this time frame:

- Reed's participation with the Illuminati in *NEW AVENGERS* was due to his having a back-door to contact Earth that he didn't tell the rest of the FF about. He was, indeed, on that search for a cure to his condition; however, the impending destruction of the universe was worth a few minor interruptions.
- In *AGE OF ULTRON*, the FF returned to Earth after Ultron had taken over, and only Sue survived. Once the timeline was reset, of course, none of that needed to happen, so it didn't.
- One of the reasons Tony pushed for the expansion of the Avengers' roster seen in *AVENGERS* at that time was to help free him up to spend more time dealing with the incursions. In fact, he was one of the few Avengers who did not go into space to fight the Builders in the "Infinity" storyline, precisely so he could stay on Earth to deal with incursions.
- I've gotten the impression that, possibly, the multiple time travel trips seen in *AGE OF ULTRON* are connected to the collapse of the Marvel multiverse. While it's not the only possible cause (the events happening out in the universe during "War of Kings" and "Realm of Kings" definitely ripped a hole in the universe), the strong warnings and concern about using time travel to fix the problem, followed by the fact that there were multiple trips by the same people to the same time, seems like a strong candidate for causing major problems. This is certainly not explicitly stated anywhere; I simply feel like it was being hinted at.

Looking at your specific question, it looks like you're asking about the first storylines in Jonathan Hickman's runs on *AVENGERS* and *NEW AVENGERS*, and *AGE OF ULTRON*. If I had to try to place those on a timeline, I'd tend to put *NEW AVENGERS* 1-6 first, then *AVENGERS* 1-6, then *AVENGERS: AGE OF ULTRON*.

Why?

- As I noted, one of the reasons Tony promoted the expansion of the team was the threat of the incursions.
- *AVENGERS* requires that the selection and organization of the new team have all happened. Logical, all this would have been going on while the Illuminati (inclkuding Steve Rogers at that point) were figuring things out from their end. Hence, the first storyline in *AVENGERS* following the first storyline in *NEW AVENGERS*.
- *AGE OF ULTRON* didn't start until we were already well into the other two storylines. Therefore, place it after they conclude, as that's the simplest solution. Since Ultron's attack, in the final version of the timeline, wasn't really that much of a threat overall (no worse by comparison that some of his other attacks, certainly), there wasn't much discussion of it in the other books outside of the *.AU* issues.